# Find Duplicated Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

how can i find duplicated records in sql server .
it will be good ,if i can find the records except the latest record.
because i want to delete all the records other than the latest one.
i am planning to do this by putting all the records except the latest into a temp table and delete the  original records based on the id of temp table

### example

```
employeeID     EmployeeName

1                       A
2                       B   
3                       A
4                       A
5                       B
```

i want to select 1,3 (in case of employeeName='A')
i want to select 2 in case of employeeName='B'

Comment: What about `4` for **A**?

Comment: He literally just said he wanted to keep the most recent one =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Duplicate records of 'A'**

```
SELECT      employeeID
FROM        Emp AS A
WHERE       EmployeeName = 'A' AND 
            employeeID <> (SELECT MAX(employeeID)
                           FROM   Emp
                           WHERE  EmployeeName = A.EmployeeName)
```

**All Dulplicates**

```
SELECT      employeeID
FROM        Emp AS A
WHERE       employeeID <> (SELECT MAX(employeeID)
                           FROM   Emp
                           WHERE  EmployeeName = A.EmployeeName)
```

**To Delete Duplicate records**

```
DELETE FROM Emp
WHERE  employeeID NOT IN (SELECT   MAX(employeeID)
                          FROM     Emp
                          GROUP BY EmployeeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add Identity column to the original table
(called employeeNo)

```
declare @T table(E_Name nvarchar(255), C int, Max_ID int)

insert @T
select employeeName, count(1), max(employeeNo)
from employees
group by employeeName 
having count(1)>1

delete employees
from employees
left join @T on E_Name = employeeName 
where C is not null and Max_ID <> employeeNo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE employeeID not in 
(
    SELECT     MAX(employeeID)
    FROM         Table_1
    GROUP BY EmployeeName
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects all the old duplicates from example table.

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE employeeID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(employeeID) _ FROM example)
```